# How do I add multiple endings to a surveyjs survey?

Tags: reactjs, survey, surveyjs

I created a survey using surveyjs's online designer and incorporated it into my web app. I would like to add two endings to the survey though.

If user clicks "no" for questions 2,3 or 4, it shows' the message "sorry ... thank you" instead of the default "thank you for ..." that I have as the current ending under the "completedHtml" section.

I essentially want to add two possible endings for the user tied to the logic rules I've set.

I've tried to just create a new "completedHtml[2]" section think (I'm sure the proper term) but I can't figure out how to redirect the logic from just **end survey** to **end with completedHtml2 page**.

Comment: The [Conditional Logic and Dynamic Texts](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/design-survey/conditional-logic) section of the docs might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [survey.completedHtmlOnCondition](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/survey-data-model#completedHtmlOnCondition) property.
You can see how it is implemented in our [NPS example](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/nps-question/reactjs#content-code).

Thank you,
SurveyJS Team